# Angularjs, Datepicker one day beind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datepicker

I understand that the datepicker (I'm using [AngularStrap's datepicker](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/)) is "behind" a day because of how dates are calculated in javascript. My problem is, how to I get it to not take the timezone into consideration and just stick with the entered date... no adjustments?

I select February 1, 2014 in the datepicker. My value on the screen is 2/1/2014 and I want that value to be saved. However, the datepicker turns this into `Fri Jan 31 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)` apparently because it subtracts the 5 hours for my timezone from the entered date. I do not want this. If I enter 2/1/2014 I want that date, regardless of the timezone.

What is the best way to intercept/change/edit this value so that entering 2/1/2014 gives me exactly that date... no conversion for timezone? Should I modify the datepicker code itself (this seems like a bad idea)? Should I change the value myself prior to sending it to the backend by adding in some sort of offset? If so, how do you add time to a value that console displays as `Fri Jan 31 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)`?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with a custom directive https://gist.github.com/weberste/354a3f0a9ea58e0ea0de

It's for Angular Bootstrap datepicker but I guess it should work for AngularStrap datepicker as well since it only depends on the corresponding ngModel rather than the datepicker itself.

Essentially, I'm reformatting the value whenever a date is selected on the datepicker (this value, a yyyy-mm-dd formatted string, will be stored on the model) and whenever the model is accessed to populate the view, I need to wrap it in a Date object again so datepicker handles it properly.

In other words, it is exactly doing the interceptions that you ask for in your question.

Comment: could you show that gist in context? got the same problem but your directive doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is kind of old but since there is no accepted solution I thought I'd offer what *finally* worked for me after lots of messing around:

The issue in my case was that the datepicker was using the wrong timezone so when I would try to edit an event, the wrong date would display even though the correct date was stored in the db. The following fixed it for me:

```
 var evDate = new Date(data.eventDate); //data.eventDate is the date string
 evDate.setMinutes(evDate.getMinutes() + evDate.getTimezoneOffset()); 

 $scope.eventInfo.eventDate = evDate;
```

I found this solution here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2628

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind loading another resource, then I would recommend using MomentJS as it takes the pain out of dates in JavaScript. You can do something like `moment(datepicker value).local()' to get the date without the timezone offset.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/

Comment: This won't work because I already only provide the values for month day and year to the datepicker. I do not provide the time zone, it automatically does this and that's the problem. The datepicker sees, for example, 2/1/14 and it converts that to February 1, 2014 00:00:00 and then subtracts my timezone from it, giving me January 28, 2014 at 19:00:00. Passing it the value from moment won't get around this problem.

Comment: the model for date picker is returning a value that's different from that you entered so why not just adjust that using momentJS before sending to the backend?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way. convert that date to string first. here is the code.

```
 var SelectDate = $scope.GetFormattedDate(Date.parse($("#Date").datepicker("getDate")));            
     $scope.GetFormattedDate = function (CalDate) {
            var re = /-?\d+/;
            var WDate = CalDate.toString();
            var m = re.exec(WDate);
            var lastDate = new Date(parseInt(m[0]));
            var mm = lastDate.getMonth() + 1;
            var dd = lastDate.getDate();
            var yyyy = lastDate.getFullYear();
            var formattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

            return formattedDate;
        }
```

Now Pass SelectDate to your controller. bingo problem has been resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Guys if you are experiencing this problem is because probably,you are reactivily ,puting data in  boostrap datepicker.This solution worked for me.
First you check if date is null

```
dateBegin===null?dateBegin=null:dateBegin = new Date(formatDate(dateBegin,'yyyy-MM-dd','en'));
```

**if is null you set its value to null which you are going putt in your Form Group and in Form Group Control

```
this.ugovorForm = new FormGroup({'dateBegin':new FormControl(dateBegin)})
```

else you will set Date and format it using formatDate property , provided by Angular.I was struguling with this problem for along time.And its because I'm loading dates from Database.Good Luck;