# AngularJS datepicker directive changing selected date when I change timezone

Tags: javascript, angular

Heey everyone, can someone help with my angularJS directive, I kind of can't make it work and spent too much time on it and on investigating the problem but still can't solve it.

I have this angular directive:

```
function link(scope, element, attr, ctrls) {
        var ngModelController = ctrls[0];

        // called with a JavaScript Date object when picked from the datepicker
        ngModelController.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
            // undo the timezone adjustment we did during the formatting
            viewValue.setMinutes(viewValue.getMinutes() - viewValue.getTimezoneOffset());
            // we just want a local date in ISO format
            return viewValue.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
        });

        // called with a 'yyyy-mm-dd' string to format
        ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
            if (!modelValue) {
                return undefined;
            }
            // date constructor will apply timezone deviations from UTC (i.e. if locale is behind UTC 'dt' will be one day behind)
            var dt = new Date(modelValue);
            // 'undo' the timezone offset again (so we end up on the original date again)
            dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + dt.getTimezoneOffset());
            return dt;
        });
    }
```

Which I think it's the same as this one: https://gist.github.com/weberste/354a3f0a9ea58e0ea0de

And it is provided here as a solution to a similar problem I have:
[Angularjs, Datepicker one day beind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874540/angularjs-datepicker-one-day-beind)

But this directive and the answers in the feed does not solved my problem.

The problem I am having is that whenever I select a date from the datepicker and I am in Central European Time the date is shown and selected as it should let's take 6th of June for an example: [image]

After I manually change my timezone to US - Eastern Daylight Time and refresh my page the day before is selected in the datepicker directive: [image]

Can anyone help, I tried couple of things by setting the time to utc and everything, but nothing helped.